# Routing error - passing a parameter to update action from link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, parameter-passing, rails-routing

I have a booking model, I want the user to confirm/reject a booking by clicking on one link or the other. I'm trying to avoid having to create a form.

here is how I tried implementing it:

```
<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
    <%= link_to "Confirm", appointment_booking_path(@appointment, booking, :status => "confirmed"), :method => :put, confirm: 'Are you sure?', :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
    <%= link_to "Reject", appointment_booking_path(@appointment, booking, :status => "rejected"), :method => :put, confirm: 'Are you sure?',:class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
<%end%>
```

I am getting this error upon clicking on one of the links:

```
NoMethodError in BookingsController#update
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:64:in `update'
```

Bookings is nested within appointments. Here is my rake Routes:

```
                          PUT    /appointments/:appointment_id/bookings/:id(.:format) 
appointment_booking       GET    /appointments/:appointment_id/bookings/:id(.:format)
edit_appointment_booking  GET    /appointments/:appointment_id/bookings/:id/edit(.:format)
```

BookingController Update action:

```
line 64*    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:booking][:appointment_id])
            @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
```

Let me know if you need any more information. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at your rake routes, and you'll see it's `appointment_booking` and not `appointment_bookings` (i.e. no `s` at the end of `bookings`).

You'll also need to pass in the appointment instance as the first argument. Assuming your appointment is called `@appointment`, try this:

```
<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
  <%= link_to "Confirm", appointment_booking_path(@appointment, booking, :status => "confirmed"), :method => :put, confirm: 'Are you sure?', :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
  <%= link_to "Reject", appointment_booking_path(@appointment, booking, :status => "rejected"), :method => :put, confirm: 'Are you sure?',:class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: When I do that I get this error: 

Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"bookings", :status=>"confirmed", :appointment_id=>#<Booking id: 1, appointment_date: "2012-10-04", start_time: "2000-01-01 17:30:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 17:30:00", name: "jon", appointment_id: 1, status: "booked", created_at: "2012-10-03 21:44:24", updated_at: "2012-10-03 21:44:24">}

Comment: Is this the best way of doing this? or is there a better method?

Comment: Oh sorry you also need to pass in the appointment as the first argument, so `appointment_booking_path(@appointment, booking, :status => "confirmed)`. I'm assuming here that the appointment for the page you're currently on is called `@appointment`.

Comment: hmm.. now I get this: NoMethodError in BookingsController#update

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass. I'll add update controller above.

Comment: You're getting the error because `params[:booking]` is nil. Try reversing the order, first assign `@booking = Booking.find(params[:id])` and then `@appointment = @booking.appointment`. (You don't need to find both of them from the DB, since a booking only belongs_to one appointment you can just access it through the association.)